# Specific alignment with model

Tags: alignment

I am trying to obtain the result shown in the picture below, a letter aligned to the left (without alinea) and a text starting at the same length. Should I use enumerate?

I would appreciate some help :)

[image: What I am trying to get]

Comment: How big is this list? Should it be breakable across the page boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent\hrulefill% REMOVE THIS TO GET RID OF LINE
\begin{itemize}[align=left,itemsep=-3pt]
\item[$\theta$] Shape parameter in using the relationship between
  the additional sales price and product...
\item[$A$] Ordering cost per order...
\item[$B$] Promotional budget...
\item[$C$] Annual purchasing cost...
\item[$H$] Annual holding cost...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)